# How do I prevent a menu in switch function from repeating itself?

Tags: c++

In this code the menu will appear twice after a section of a or b is made, how do i prevent that from happening?  I suspect that it has something to do with cin.get capturing a space perhaps from the first cout statement.  If that's the case then the solution would be something that will consume that space.  I know getline works for strings but this is a char data type.  Also a quick related question, is there a piece of code that acts like getline(cin << ws, stringName) does for strings but for char data types?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;


void displayMenu();

int main()
{
    char cSelection;
    string sSelection;

    //Create menu
    const char OPTION_READING = 'A', OPTION_READINGTWO = 'B', OPTION_ENDING = 'C';

    do
    {
        displayMenu();
        cout << "\nPlease choose an option" << endl << endl;
        cin.get(cSelection);

        //respond to choice
        switch (cSelection)
        {
        case OPTION_READING:
        case 'a':
            cout << "You picked 1" << endl;
            break;

        case OPTION_READINGTWO:
        case 'b':
            cout << "You picked 2" << endl;
            break;

        case OPTION_ENDING:
        case 'c':
            cout << "Thank you for using this program!";
            return 0;

        default:
            cout << cSelection << " " << "is an invalid choice";


        }
    } while (toupper(sSelection[0] != OPTION_ENDING));


}
void displayMenu()
{

    cout << "\t \t \t" "Menu" << endl << endl;
    cout << "A. Option 1\n";
    cout << "B. Option 2\n";
    cout << "C. Quit program";

}
```

Comment: Its not a space in `cout`. Its the newline you entered along with your menu choice character.  Consume the newline in one fashion or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `cin.get();` after `cin.get(cSelection);` to clear newline.

Answer (score 1):

with `#include <limits>`

after

```
cin.get(cSelection);
```

you may add:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your additional menu hit is from consumption of a newline char that is still in the input stream. Consume it any number of ways, one of which is shown below. I also took the liberty to fix your `while` condition, which was not correctly expressed (you were passing a `bool` to `toupper`, which was clearly not what you wanted. Likewise I changed the use of `sSelection[0]`, which is not initialized in this code to `cSelection`. As it was, you would invoke *undefined behavior*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

void displayMenu();

int main()
{
    int cSelection;
    string sSelection;

    //Create menu
    const char OPTION_READING = 'A', OPTION_READINGTWO = 'B', OPTION_ENDING = 'C';

    do
    {
        displayMenu();
        cout << "\nPlease choose an option" << endl << endl;
        if ((cSelection = cin.get()) == EOF)
            break;

        // eat newline character
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        //respond to choice
        switch (cSelection)
        {
            case OPTION_READING:
            case 'a':
                cout << "You picked 1" << endl;
                break;

            case OPTION_READINGTWO:
            case 'b':
                cout << "You picked 2" << endl;
                break;

            case OPTION_ENDING:
            case 'c':
                cout << "Thank you for using this program!\n";
                return 0;

            default:
                cout << cSelection << " " << "is an invalid choice";


        }
    } while (std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(cSelection)) != OPTION_ENDING);


}

void displayMenu()
{
    cout << "\t \t \t" "Menu" << endl << endl;
    cout << "A. Option 1\n";
    cout << "B. Option 2\n";
    cout << "C. Quit program";
}
```

**How It Works**

That `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` may look a little cryptic, but it really isn't that bad. C++11 provides a very nice template class called [**`std::numeric_limits`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). Given a numeric *type*, you can fire a static member function of the class and get the numeric limits (min, max, etc) of the type. There are tons of of specializations of that template for every native language type. I advise following the link I provided and checking out how it works and all that it offers.

In our case we're interested in consuming as many chars as possible until we reach a newline, which will be discarded. We use the [**`ignore()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) method from our input stream, `std::cin`, to accomplish the skipping. Therefore:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

effectively says "Skip as many chars as you have to looking for a newline. If you find a newline, skip it, then return. Consume as many as you have to, up to EOF if needed."

It may look a little cryptic, but its not uncommon at all, and quite effective.

Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Hey WhozCraig helpful as always! Anywho, I am reluctant to make changes on the while condition.  You see a code was given to us to work with (which nobody in the class fully understands yet as we have not even reached chapters that deal with those parameters inside the while condition) and so because I don't understand why there is a cSelection[0] I'll assume it has something to do with some other stuff in the original non abstracted stuff.

Thanks everyone

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee The fiend that wrote that while-condition was high on something, because `toupper` isn't going to do bo-diddly with a `bool`. and as it is never a null-char, it will *always* be true. And as the code is right now, it will also always invoke undefined behavior, since the string is zero-length. If you think that hard-`return` is in the exit-choice-code as an after thought, it isn't. its because of the broken while-condition. Anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: I put that part in there myself because i thought it was a simple/safe way to exit the loop and because, frankly, I didn't know what was happening inside the parameter field for that while condition.  Anywho, i have more questions to ask.  I'll look to see if there's a similar questions somewhere.